# How to get Gstreamer to capture udp stream of images pushed individually by buffer

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer

I currently have a gstreamer pipeline in python that pushes camera images to the pipeline buffer, and displays with autovideosink. However I'm having issues pushing it to a udp pipeline.

what currently works in a python program:

```
udp_sink_pipeline = "appsrc name=source ! image/jpeg,framerate=(fraction)30/1  ! decodebin ! videoscale ! capsfilter caps=video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1  ! queue ! autovideosink"
```

what I want to work:

```
udp_sink_pipeline = "appsrc name=source ! image/jpeg,framerate=(fraction)30/1  ! decodebin ! videoscale ! capsfilter caps=video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1  ! queue ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1,port=5200"
```

how i attempt to capture it:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5200 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! autovideosink sync=false
```

Since no images show up, I'm not exactly sure if there problem is with the client or server side.